# Why can't I view title when I set a button to disabled?

Tags: jquery, html

Has anyone experienced this:

```
<button disabled="disabled" class="sel" title="Task: 22">@i</button>
```

Looks good but when I put this in a page the title does not appear. Is there any solution that can show me the title and still have the button remain disabled? How about some jQuery to show bubble text but without the need for a plugin?

How about if I convert my button to an address link. Is there an easy way that I can show title in the same way as with input buttons?

Comment: Not sure if this is a accidental, but you're missing a double quote to close off the title attr.

Comment: Missing closing quotation mark on `title`

Comment: Is it a typo that you left the ending quotation off the title? Lol... the first thing everyone asked

Comment: Hello, can you try with firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve some cross browser problems with jQuery

[Here is the best I could come up with on short notice](http://jsfiddle.net/NullRef/aUYmf/3/)

Not ideal because the `mouseenter` is a little finicky. Perhaps someone can improve it. EDIT: you would also have to play with the styling to make it look "tooltip" ish.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not a typo that you left off the closing double-quote on the title attribute, then that's your problem.

Comment: Seems like a firefox problem :-(